# How can I get a list of all windows/system DLLs and their versions?

Tags: windows, dll, report

I'd like to have the following report:

All DLLs in %WIN_DIR% in my PC, and in its sub-folders, recursively.

For each DLL found, I'd like to have its file version, product version etc. (as it can be found by looking at the file's properties).

Do you know any utility that can prepare such report?

**PS**: I know I can write a script, but that's not the question here, since this should be executed as a "descent" program/executable, and a script host is unavailable due to security policy.

Thanks for any help/lead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx):

```
PS C:\Windows> Get-ChildItem c:\windows -include *.dll -recurse | foreach-object { "{0}" -f [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_) }
```

a few lines of example output:

```
File:             C:\windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.JScript\7.0.5000.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
InternalName:     Microsoft.JScript.dll
OriginalFilename: Microsoft.JScript.dll
FileVersion:      7.10.3052.4
FileDescription:  Microsoftr JScript Engine
Product:          Microsoftr JScript .NET
ProductVersion:   7.10.3052.4
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)


File:C:\windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.StdFormat\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.stdformat.dll
InternalName:
OriginalFilename:
FileVersion:      7.00.9466
FileDescription:
Product:          Microsoftr Visual Studio .NET
ProductVersion:   7.00.9466
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         English (United States)
....
```

If you'd like to save this to a file:

```
PS C:\Windows> Get-ChildItem c:\windows -include *.dll -recurse | foreach-object { "{0}" -f [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_) } > C:\DLL_Versions.txt
```

this would save all of the output to `C:\DLL_Versions.txt`.

Comment: Alternative suggestion: `Get-ChildItem $Env:windir -Recurse -Include *.dll -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_) } | Format-Table { [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FileName) },*Version,*Description` – nicer table output, no visible error messages about unreachable directories, no string fiddling, no hardcoded Windows directory.

Comment: And you should really switch to Lucida Console or Consolas as your console font. The lack of Unicode output in your listing is ... disturbing :-)

Comment: Good suggestions, but then the filename heading is **[IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.filename)** and output is cut off even when piped to a file. Feel free to edit and improve my answer, I have to go to work :\

Comment: Thanks for a great script. Is there a tool that makes such reports?

Comment: Not that I am aware of unfortunately

Comment: ok, thanks for the script. accepted, although the original question was about a utility.